# Retrieve values from Json and update the XML

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb, domparser

I am trying to combine multiple xmls into one xml using DOM parser. I am fairly new to this process. I am having issue while updating the values and the order of the xml which I will be getting from JSON. Here, # of xmls to combine is equal to the # json.

```
        Document outputDoc = db.parse(baseXml);    
        Node outputNode = outputDoc.getElementsByTagName("Entry").item(0);

        for (String inputXml : inputXmls) {
            Document inputDoc = db.parse(inputXml);
            inputDoc.normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = inputDoc.getElementsByTagName("Person");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node copiedNode = outputDoc.importNode(nodeList.item(i),true);
                outputNode.appendChild(copiedNode);
            }
        }
        processXml(outputDoc, file);

    }

    private static void processXml(Document xml, File file) throws TransformerException {
        Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xml);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        tf.transform(source, result);
    }
```

Base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Entry>
</Entry>
```

xml1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Entry>
    <Person>
        <Name>
            <NameTitle>
                <Value>Name</Value>
            </NameTitle>
        </Name>
        <Details>
            <PersonDetails>
                <Name>
                    <NameValue></NameValue>
                </Name>
            </PersonDetails>
        </Details>
    </Person>
</Entry>
```

json1.json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "json": [
        {
            "nameTitle": "Full Name",
            "displayOrder": 2
        },
        {
            "nameValue": "John Doe",
            "displayOrder": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I am getting the following'

```
 <Entry>
   <Person>
        <Name>
            <NameTitle>
                <Value>Name</Value>
            </NameTitle>
        </Name>
        <Details>
            <PersonDetails>
                <Name>
                    <NameValue/>
                </Name>
            </PersonDetails>
        </Details>
    </Person>
    </Entry>
```

This is what is expected outcome

```
 <Entry>
    <Person>
        <Details>
            <PersonDetails>
                <Name>
                    <NameValue>John Doe</NameValue>
                </Name>
            </PersonDetails>
        </Details>
        <Name>
            <NameTitle>
                <Value>Full Name</Value>
            </NameTitle>
        </Name>
    </Person>
</Entry>
```